# Show list recursively using tree structure in javascript

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree

I have an array/object result from database which is returned from controller to ajax response

```
    "success": true,
    "error": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "folder_name": "root-fol",
            "parent_folder_id": null,
            "folder_id": "420",
            "media_id": "1801",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "video",
            "media_name": "f2-vid",
            "size": "531.13 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "video\/mp4"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "root-fol",
            "parent_folder_id": null,
            "folder_id": "420",
            "media_id": "1802",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "audio",
            "media_name": "f2-aud",
            "size": "433.52 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "audio\/mpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "root-fol",
            "parent_folder_id": null,
            "folder_id": "420",
            "media_id": "1803",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "document",
            "media_name": "f2-doc",
            "size": "2.96 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "application\/pdf"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "root-fol",
            "parent_folder_id": null,
            "folder_id": "420",
            "media_id": "1804",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "photo",
            "media_name": "f2-img",
            "size": "3.21 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "image\/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "root-fol",
            "parent_folder_id": null,
            "folder_id": "420",
            "media_id": "1805",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "photo",
            "media_name": "f2-img_1",
            "size": "121.89 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "image\/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder2",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "421",
            "media_id": "1791",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "photo",
            "media_name": "f2-sf2-img_1",
            "size": "121.89 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "image\/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder2",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "421",
            "media_id": "1792",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "video",
            "media_name": "f2-sf2-vid",
            "size": "531.13 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "video\/mp4"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder2",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "421",
            "media_id": "1793",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "document",
            "media_name": "f2-sf2-doc",
            "size": "2.96 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "application\/pdf"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder2",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "421",
            "media_id": "1794",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "audio",
            "media_name": "f2-sf2-aud",
            "size": "433.52 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "audio\/mpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder2",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "421",
            "media_id": "1795",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "photo",
            "media_name": "f2-sf2-img",
            "size": "3.21 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "image\/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "innerfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "421",
            "folder_id": "422",
            "media_id": "1786",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "photo",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-if1-img_1",
            "size": "121.89 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "image\/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "innerfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "421",
            "folder_id": "422",
            "media_id": "1787",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "photo",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-if1-img",
            "size": "3.21 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "image\/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "innerfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "421",
            "folder_id": "422",
            "media_id": "1788",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "audio",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-if1-aud",
            "size": "433.52 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "audio\/mpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "innerfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "421",
            "folder_id": "422",
            "media_id": "1789",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "video",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-if1-vid",
            "size": "531.13 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "video\/mp4"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "innerfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "421",
            "folder_id": "422",
            "media_id": "1790",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "document",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-if1-doc",
            "size": "2.96 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "application\/pdf"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "423",
            "media_id": "1796",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "document",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-doc",
            "size": "2.96 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "application\/pdf"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "423",
            "media_id": "1797",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "photo",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-img_1",
            "size": "121.89 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "image\/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "423",
            "media_id": "1798",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "audio",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-aud",
            "size": "433.52 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "audio\/mpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "423",
            "media_id": "1799",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "photo",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-img",
            "size": "3.21 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "image\/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "folder_name": "subfolder1",
            "parent_folder_id": "420",
            "folder_id": "423",
            "media_id": "1800",
            "user_id": "405",
            "media_type": "video",
            "media_name": "f2-sf1-vid",
            "size": "531.13 KB",
            "dimension": "",
            "collection_id": "80",
            "media_format": "video\/mp4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to show list as

```
<ul>
        <li>root fol
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-folder"></i> subfolder2
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-folder"></i> innerfolder1
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-image"></i> f2-sf1-if1-img_1</li>
                                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-image"></i> f2-sf1-if1-img</li>
                                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-audio"></i> f2-sf1-if1-aud</li>
                                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-video"></i> f2-sf1-if1-vid</li>
                                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-document"></i> f2-sf1-if1-doc</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-image"></i> f2-sf2-img_1</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-video"></i> f2-sf2-vid</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-audio"></i> f2-sf2-aud</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-document"></i> f2-sf2-doc</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-image"></i> f2-sf2-img</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-folder"></i> subfolder1
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-document"></i> f2-sf1-doc</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-image"></i> f2-sf1-img_1</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-audio"></i> f2-sf1-aud</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-image"></i> f2-sf1-img</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-video"></i> f2-sf1-vid</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-video"></i> f2-vid</li>
                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-audio"></i> f2-aud</li>
                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-document"></i> f2-doc</li>
                <li><i class="fa-regular fa-image"></i> f2-img</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I tried to convert json array into tree structure like

```
Array
        (
            [folder_name] => root-fol
            [folder_id] => 420
            [result_type] => folder
            [media_type] => folder
            [user_id] => 405
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [folder_id] => 421
                            [folder_name] => subfolder2
                            [parent_id] => 420
                            [result_type] => folder
                            [media_type] => folder
                            [user_id] => 405
                            [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [folder_id] => 422
                                        [folder_name] => innerfolder1
                                        [parent_id] => 421
                                        [result_type] => folder
                                        [media_type] => folder
                                        [user_id] => 405
                                        [media] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [media_id] => 1786
                                                        [media_name] => f2-sf1-if1-img_1
                                                        [size] => 121.89 KB
                                                        [media_format] => image/jpeg
                                                        [result_type] => media
                                                        [media_type] => photo
                                                        [user_id] => 405
                                                    )
            
                                                [1] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [media_id] => 1787
                                                        [media_name] => f2-sf1-if1-img
                                                        [size] => 3.21 KB
                                                        [media_format] => image/jpeg
                                                        [result_type] => media
                                                        [media_type] => photo
                                                        [user_id] => 405
                                                    )
            
                                                [2] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [media_id] => 1788
                                                        [media_name] => f2-sf1-if1-aud
                                                        [size] => 433.52 KB
                                                        [media_format] => audio/mpeg
                                                        [result_type] => media
                                                        [media_type] => audio
                                                        [user_id] => 405
                                                    )
            
                                                [3] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [media_id] => 1789
                                                        [media_name] => f2-sf1-if1-vid
                                                        [size] => 531.13 KB
                                                        [media_format] => video/mp4
                                                        [result_type] => media
                                                        [media_type] => video
                                                        [user_id] => 405
                                                    )
            
                                                [4] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [media_id] => 1790
                                                        [media_name] => f2-sf1-if1-doc
                                                        [size] => 2.96 KB
                                                        [media_format] => application/pdf
                                                        [result_type] => media
                                                        [media_type] => document
                                                        [user_id] => 405
                                                    )
            
                                            )
            
                                    )
                            [media] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [media_id] => 1791
                                            [media_name] => f2-sf2-img_1
                                            [size] => 121.89 KB
                                            [media_format] => image/jpeg
                                            [result_type] => media
                                            [media_type] => photo
                                            [user_id] => 405
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [media_id] => 1792
                                            [media_name] => f2-sf2-vid
                                            [size] => 531.13 KB
                                            [media_format] => video/mp4
                                            [result_type] => media
                                            [media_type] => video
                                            [user_id] => 405
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [media_id] => 1793
                                            [media_name] => f2-sf2-doc
                                            [size] => 2.96 KB
                                            [media_format] => application/pdf
                                            [result_type] => media
                                            [media_type] => document
                                            [user_id] => 405
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [media_id] => 1794
                                            [media_name] => f2-sf2-aud
                                            [size] => 433.52 KB
                                            [media_format] => audio/mpeg
                                            [result_type] => media
                                            [media_type] => audio
                                            [user_id] => 405
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [media_id] => 1795
                                            [media_name] => f2-sf2-img
                                            [size] => 3.21 KB
                                            [media_format] => image/jpeg
                                            [result_type] => media
                                            [media_type] => photo
                                            [user_id] => 405
                                        )

                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [folder_id] => 423
                            [folder_name] => subfolder1
                            [parent_id] => 420
                            [result_type] => folder
                            [media_type] => folder
                            [user_id] => 405
                            [media] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [media_id] => 1796
                                            [media_name] => f2-sf1-doc
                                            [size] => 2.96 KB
                                            [media_format] => application/pdf
                                            [result_type] => media
                                            [media_type] => document
                                            [user_id] => 405
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [media_id] => 1797
                                            [media_name] => f2-sf1-img_1
                                            [size] => 121.89 KB
                                            [media_format] => image/jpeg
                                            [result_type] => media
                                            [media_type] => photo
                                            [user_id] => 405
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [media_id] => 1798
                                            [media_name] => f2-sf1-aud
                                            [size] => 433.52 KB
                                            [media_format] => audio/mpeg
                                            [result_type] => media
                                            [media_type] => audio
                                            [user_id] => 405
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [media_id] => 1799
                                            [media_name] => f2-sf1-img
                                            [size] => 3.21 KB
                                            [media_format] => image/jpeg
                                            [result_type] => media
                                            [media_type] => photo
                                            [user_id] => 405
                                        )

                                )

                        )
            [media] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [media_id] => 1801
                            [media_name] => f2-vid
                            [size] => 531.13 KB
                            [media_format] => video/mp4
                            [result_type] => media
                            [media_type] => video
                            [user_id] => 405
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [media_id] => 1802
                            [media_name] => f2-aud
                            [size] => 433.52 KB
                            [media_format] => audio/mpeg
                            [result_type] => media
                            [media_type] => audio
                            [user_id] => 405
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [media_id] => 1803
                            [media_name] => f2-doc
                            [size] => 2.96 KB
                            [media_format] => application/pdf
                            [result_type] => media
                            [media_type] => document
                            [user_id] => 405
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [media_id] => 1804
                            [media_name] => f2-img
                            [size] => 3.21 KB
                            [media_format] => image/jpeg
                            [result_type] => media
                            [media_type] => photo
                            [user_id] => 405
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [media_id] => 1805
                            [media_name] => f2-img_1
                            [size] => 121.89 KB
                            [media_format] => image/jpeg
                            [result_type] => media
                            [media_type] => photo
                            [user_id] => 405
                        )

                )

        )
```

I tried below recursive function to convert an array to tree structure but didn't get desired ouput.

```
$new_array = array();
        foreach($jayParsedAry['data'] AS $a) {
            $new_array[$a['parent_id']][] = $a;
        }
        // echo '<pre>';print_r($new_array);exit;
        
        $response = $this->buildTree_($jayParsedAry['data']);
        echo '<pre>';print_r($response);
        exit;

function buildTree_(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
        $branch = array();
        
        // echo '<pre>';print_r($branch);exit;
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
                // echo '<pre> element ';print_r($element);
                $children = $this->buildTree_($elements, $element['folder_id']);
                if ($children) {
                    $element['children'] = $children;
                }
                $branch[] = $element;
            }
        }
        return $branch;
    }
```

There can be multilevel tree structure as it is dynamic. I am stuck in this.
Any help would be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: You want to print or just convert the data to a recursive structure?

Comment: @SalmanA I want to print in view

Answer (score 0):

I would first create an associative array keyed by `folder_id` so you don't have to scan the array over and over again to find certain folder ids. Then create the nested structure iteratively, since you have the parent folder id for each item.

Finally create HTML from that tree structure with a recursive function:

```
function to_tree($data) {
    $map[null] = ["children" => [], "media" => []];
    
    foreach($data as $obj) {
        $map[$obj->folder_id] = [
            "folder_name" => $obj->folder_name,
            "folder_id" => $obj->folder_id,
            "user_id" => $obj->user_id,
            "user_type" => "folder",
            "media_type" => "folder",
            "children" => [],
        ];
    }
    foreach($data as $obj) {
        $type = explode("/", $obj->media_format)[0];
        $map[$obj->parent_folder_id]["children"][$obj->folder_id] =& $map[$obj->folder_id];
        $map[$obj->folder_id]["media"][] = [
            "media_id" => $obj->media_id,
            "media_name" => $obj->media_name,
            "size" => $obj->size,
            "media_format" => $obj->media_format,
            "result_type" => "media",
            "media_type" => $type === "application" ? "document" : $type,
            "user_id" => $obj->user_id,
        ];
    }
    return $map[null];
}

function to_html($folder) {
    $html = "<ul>\n";
    foreach($folder["children"] as $subfolder) {
        $html .= "<li><i class='fa-regular fa-folder'></i>$subfolder[folder_name]\n" 
              . to_html($subfolder) . "</li>\n";
    }
    foreach($folder["media"] as $medium) {
        $html .= "<li><i class='fa-regular fa-$medium[media_type]'></i>$medium[media_name]</li>\n";
    }
    return "$html</ul>\n";
}
```

Run like this after you have `$jayParsedAry`:

```
$root = to_tree($jayParsedAry->data);
$html = to_html($root);
```

For the example you have given the HTML will be:

```html
<ul>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-folder'></i>root-fol
<ul>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-folder'></i>subfolder2
<ul>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-folder'></i>innerfolder1
<ul>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-image'></i>f2-sf1-if1-img_1</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-image'></i>f2-sf1-if1-img</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-audio'></i>f2-sf1-if1-aud</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-video'></i>f2-sf1-if1-vid</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-document'></i>f2-sf1-if1-doc</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-image'></i>f2-sf2-img_1</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-video'></i>f2-sf2-vid</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-document'></i>f2-sf2-doc</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-audio'></i>f2-sf2-aud</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-image'></i>f2-sf2-img</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-folder'></i>subfolder1
<ul>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-document'></i>f2-sf1-doc</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-image'></i>f2-sf1-img_1</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-audio'></i>f2-sf1-aud</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-image'></i>f2-sf1-img</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-video'></i>f2-sf1-vid</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-video'></i>f2-vid</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-audio'></i>f2-aud</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-document'></i>f2-doc</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-image'></i>f2-img</li>
<li><i class='fa-regular fa-image'></i>f2-img_1</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried same logic for tree structure using reference but unable to add media as I was using only one foreach. I will try this. :)